# Passing PHP object to script breaks javascript in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, google-sheets

I am building an application to display and manipulate statistics in wordpress.

I am getting my data from google sheets and passing it to the script through wp_localize_script.

I just noticed that doing this breaks javascript functionality in other scripts although I have no idea why.

**Specifics:**

getting the data from Sheets:

```
function get_stats_from_sheets()
{
        require_once dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/stat-interface/vendor/autoload.php';
        $apikey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
        $spreadsheetId = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
        $ranges = ["'GI'!A1:F", "'dsfdf'!A1:C", "'dfd'!A1:G", "'dsfdf'!A1:B", "'dsfdsf'!A1:D"];
        $params = ['ranges' => $ranges, 'majorDimension' => 'COLUMNS'];
        $client = new Google\Client();
        $client->setApplicationName("dsfdf");
        $client->setDeveloperKey($apikey);

        $service = new Google_Service_Sheets($client);
        $response = $service->spreadsheets_values->batchGet($spreadsheetId, $params);
        $array = (array) $response;
        $data = $array['valueRanges'];
        return $data;
}
```

Localize script and other loaded scripts:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_script_load', 11);

function my_custom_script_load(){
    if (is_page(603484)):
    wp_enqueue_script('spamspan', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/spamspan.js', array('jquery'), '0.2', true);

        wp_enqueue_style('stat', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/stat.css');
        wp_enqueue_script('chartJs', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.4/dist/Chart.min.js', '', '', true);
        wp_enqueue_script('ublcharts', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/ublcharts.js', '', '', true);
        wp_localize_script('ublcharts', 'statsData', get_stats_from_sheets());
        wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js', array('jquery'), '', false);
        wp_enqueue_style('bootstrapCss', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css');
        wp_enqueue_script('pdfmake', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.68/pdfmake.min.js', '', true);
        wp_enqueue_script('vfs_fonts', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.68/vfs_fonts.min.js', '', '', true);
        wp_register_script('stat-pdf', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/stat-pdf.js', '', '', true);
        wp_localize_script('stat-pdf', 'home_url', array('url' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri(), 'home' => get_home_url()));
        wp_enqueue_script('stat-pdf');
    endif;
}
```

Errors received:

```
spamspan.js?ver=0.2:50 
Uncaught TypeError: document.createTextNode is not a function
    at spamSpan (spamspan.js?ver=0.2:50)

_microtask.js:36 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: document.createTextNode is not a function
    at t.exports (_microtask.js:36)
    at Object.i.m.n (es6.promise.js:13)
    at i (bootstrap:19)
    at Object.i.m.n (promise.js:4)
    at i (bootstrap:19)
    at Object.i.m.n (promise.js:1)
    at i (bootstrap:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:29)
    at Object.i.m.n (pdfmake.min.js?ver=1:37)
    at i (bootstrap:19)
```

the spamspan error is not really important to me, but it was an indicator that something was breaking (the potential reason why my pdf script doesn't work).

Disabling all other scripts and enqueues, I narrowed it down to the localized data from google.

The second error message occurs when I try to generate a pdf through pdfmake.js with the data object. In both cases it says 'document.createTextNode is not a function'.

I use pdfmake.js also on other pages and there it works without problems, so I took the working code pdfmake script and stripped it down to a minimum, but I get the above error message no matter what.

Can anybody tell me why this is happening and how to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a piece of bad Javascript code I wrote.

```
     let mPoint = (document.createTextNode = point);
```

I find it still interesting that the console error lead me to anywhere else than to the faulty line in my script.

After fixing this, there were no more errors.